# Names of power-of-two bit operations on bitsets that would not assume any number interpretation

Tags: integers, software-engineering, bit-manipulation, assembly

Three commonly used functions when it comes to bit manipulation are :

- `is_pow2`: Checking that an integer is a power-of-two (only one bit  is set): $00010000 \Rightarrow yes$
- `floor_pow2`: Finds the largest integer power of two not greater than the given value $00010010 \Rightarrow 00010000$ (msb on the left, lsb on the right)
- `ceil_pow2`: Finds the smallest integer power of two not less than the given value $00010010 \Rightarrow 00100000$ (msb on the left, lsb on the right)

However, the concept of a power of two requires to assume a numeric interpretation of sets of bits. But fundamentally the functionality provided by these functions stay valid on bitsets without a numeric interpretation. For example, what `is_pow2(x)` is really asking is whether `popcount(x) == 1`. And `popcount` does not require to define any concept of power of two.

I was wondering if the three functions `is_pow2`, `floor_pow2`, `ceil_pow2` had commonly accepted names in mathematics, computer science or computer engineering which do not rely on the concept of a power of two.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a bitvector as a set, by giving names to the various bits. For example, if we name the bits in an 8-bit integer using the numbers $0,\ldots,7$ (where $0$ is the LSB and $7$ is the MSB), then $00010010$ is the same as $\{1,4\}$.

Your first function asks whether the set has size $1$. If we name the bits using numbers as above, the second function is maximum and the third is minimum.

Comment: I don't think the third function (ceil_pow2) corresponds to the least-significant set bit. It appears to be a left-shift of the most-significant set bit, so it'd be more like the max plus one (modulo whatever overflow logic was intended).